# Manipulating limit expressions when you are told that the limit of one of the expressions does not exit (Spivak - Chapter 5 Problem 23)

Tags: limits

Questions 23 a) and b) from Chapter 5 of of Spivak's *Calculus* are written as follows:

> *a*) Suppose that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ exists and is $\neq 0$. Prove that if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)$ does not exist, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x)$ does not exist.

> *b*) Prove the same result if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\ \lvert f(x)\rvert=\infty$.

---

The method for *a*) is to recognize that, because $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)\neq0$, the following expression simplifies accordingly:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}=\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x)\cdot\frac{1}{\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)}$$

Letting ${\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)}=\alpha$, we then get:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=\frac{1}{\alpha}\cdot\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x)$$

Thus, if we assert that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)\ \text{DNE}$, then it must be the case that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x)\ \text{DNE}$.

This proof strikes me as a little weird because the manipulations I carried out (when rearranging the terms) assumed that the limits existed. **Is this acceptable**?

(i.e. Does it even make sense to manipulate limit expressions if I know that the expression in question does *not* have a limit?)

---

Now, when it comes to *b*), I am not really certain of how to structure my proof. My understanding of the phrase:

> $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\ (\cdot)=\infty$

is that the limit of $(\cdot) \ \text{DNE}$. I recognize that there is a more technical definition, but I believe the statement of "$\text {DNE}$" is nonetheless valid.

As such, in the case of $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\ \lvert f(x)\rvert=\infty$, I am reluctant to recreate my former argument by bringing ${\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)}$ into the denominator. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is fine. It proves (correctly) that, if the limits $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ exist, then the limit $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)$ exists too. But you are assuming that it doesn't.

Concerning b), if $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)g(x)=l\in\Bbb R$, then, since $\lim_{x\to0}|f(x)|=\infty$, $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=0$.

Comment: For your solution to *b*), if I assume that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ does not exist, then is it also the case that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x)$ does not exist? Your version is the contrapositive, yes? If so, your version is really saying "if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x)$ exists, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ exists"

Comment: Yes: if $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)$ does not exist, then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)g(x)$ does not exist (in $\Bbb R$). And, yes, my version is the contrapositive.

Comment: Final clarification (if you're willing). When I originally compare $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}$, I am effectively saying $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}g(x) \text { exists} \iff \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)} \text { exists}$, correct? This is why I can follow my conclusion to *a*) with, "Thus, if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}g(x) \text { exists} $ is **false**, ..." etc. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

For b): $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\ \lvert f(x)\rvert=\infty$ gives, that in some neighbourhood of $0$ we have $f(x)\ne 0$ so we have right to consider $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ there. So here will work same contradiction logic as in a). By the way $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{|f(x)|}=0$.