# Question about the difference between equality and existence in the context of limits.

Tags: logic

After trying to work through some basic proofs of limits, I realized that I have some deficits in my understanding of the difference between *equality* and *existence*.

Consider the following two statements:

1. $$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \text { exists}$$
2. $$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$$

Now, consider the next two sets of statements:

1. $$g(x) \text { exists}$$
2. $$g(x)=L$$

---

Next, consider these two statements:

1. $$ f(x) \neq 0 \land g(x) \text { exists } \iff \frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)} \text{ exists}$$
2. $$ f(x) \neq 0 \land g(x)=L \iff \frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}=L $$

Finally, consider these two statements:

1. $$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \neq 0 \ \land \ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} g(x) \text{ exists} \iff \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)} \text {exists}$$
2. $$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \neq 0 \ \land \ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} g(x) =L \iff \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)} =L$$

---

The reason for the above comments is to better understand the logic that I see employed in proofs that read, for example, like the following question:

> Suppose that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ exists and is $\neq 0$. Prove that if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)$ does not exist, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x)$ does not exist

The straightforward approach for this question works out as:

> ...because $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)\neq0$, the following expression simplifies accordingly:
> $$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}=\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x)\cdot\frac{1}{\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)}$$
> Letting ${\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)}=\alpha$, we then get:
> $$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=\frac{1}{\alpha}\cdot\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x)$$
> $\color{red}{\text {Thus, if we assert that} \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}g(x) \text{ does not exist, then it must be the case that} \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x) \text{ does not exist}}$.

---

My question is about the final $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ statement. This conclusion only makes sense to me **if** the structure of the proof concludes that:

$$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) \neq 0 \ \land \ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) \text{ exists} \iff \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x) \text{ exists}$$

The reason the $\color{red}{\text {red}}$ claim makes sense relative to *this* biconditional is because if the first part of the biconditional is false (by virtue of the assertion that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) \text{ does not exist}$ ), then the second part of the biconditional is false...which means that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x) \text{ does not exist}$

**However**, I am having difficulties seeing how exactly the proof arrived at this aforementioned biconditional. To me, it seems that the proof structure concludes with:

$$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) \neq 0 \ \land \ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = L \iff \frac{1}{\alpha}\cdot\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x)=L$$

If we assert that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) \text{ does not exist}$, then certainly the first part of the biconditional is false. **But negating the second part of the biconditional** simply produces the statement: $\frac{1}{\alpha}\cdot\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x)\neq L$. This is *quite* different than claiming that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)g(x) \text{ does not exist}$.

Could someone please help me understand what exactly is going on in this proof? Thank you!

---

**Edit**: An alternative (and to me more clear) way of writing this proof is as follows:

Suppose $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x)=L$

Next, consider that, by assumption, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = M \neq 0$. Therefore, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{M}$.

It is then the case that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{L}{M}$.

But $\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}=g(x)$ so we could equivalently write:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=\frac{L}{M}$

This is a contradiction to our initial assumption that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}g(x) \text{ does not exist}$.

Comment: Not clear at all... "difference between equality and existence" ??? Equality holds between mathematical objects: two numbers, two functions, etc. Existence is the "result" of a proof or calculation: there is no natural number $n$ such that $2n=3$ vs there is a natural number $n$ such that $2n=4$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Hmmm. As a first attempt at cleaning up my question, could you tell me if the following two informal implications "make sense". The first implication is: $$ \text { if 'something' = L, then 'something' exists }$$. My claim is that this implication is always true. The second implication is: $$ \text { if 'something' exists, then 'something' = L } $$. My claim is that this implication is not always true (depending on what L equals).

Comment: Basically, we have two steps here: (i) a "conceptual" one: in order to "call" $L$ the limit of $f(x)$ we have **to prove** that the purported limit exists. "The present King of France" is not a meaningful "name" because currently France is a republic.

Comment: (ii) a mathematical one: we assume that lim $g(x)$ exists and we derive a contradiction. Conclusion: it does not exist.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA in the above proof, I do not see where the contradiction arises. Could you please highlight it for me? (It seems like you are saying that this proof is really a "proof by contradiction")

Comment: If we already know that lim g(x) does not exists, the expression lim g(x)= something makes no sense. It is like the "fallacy" above: you get a name to something that does not exist.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I wrote in an alternative proof (in an **edit** section) that follows from your input. This structure makes much more sense. What do you suspect the original proof was trying to do?

Comment: Waht is not clear to me is if you are considering a "general" logic case (in which case maybe the limit example is not the best one...) or a specific calculus example. It is a result of calculus that if lim f=A and lim g=B then lim fg=AB and (provided that B is not zero) lim f/g=A/B. This is not an iff, if we consider finite limits: we have the well-know example of $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac {\sin x }{x}=1$ But $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac 1 x$ is not finite.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay. Great. That is sort of what I figured, but I received "approval" that the original proof was valid, which is basically the source of my confusion for this entire post hah. (Original post is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109346/manipulating-limit-expressions-when-you-are-told-that-the-limit-of-one-of-the-ex)