# What is the negation of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I recently proved the following statement:

$$\text{ if } \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a^-}f(x)=M \text{ and } \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a^+}f(x)=N \text{ where } M\neq N \text{ then} \lim_{x \to a}f(x) \text{ Does Not Exist }$$

I carried out this proof by demonstrating the truth of the following FOL statement:

$$\forall L \in \mathbb R \ \exists \varepsilon \gt 0 \ \forall \delta \gt 0 \ \exists x \in \mathbb R\ \left [0 \lt |x-a| \lt \delta \land|f(x)-L| \geq \varepsilon \right ]$$

After finishing this proof, I wondered if the work I spent was rather wasteful. I knew from previous exercises that the following biconditional was true:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L \leftrightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a^-}f(x)=L \text{ and }\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a^+}f(x)=L$$

I figured because it was a biconditional, I could have taken the negations of each side, where one negation implies the other. However, I then ran into some difficulties trying to determine what the negations of the left and right statements of the biconditional are.

I came up with two possibilities:

1. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)\neq L \leftrightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a^-}f(x)\neq L \text{ or }\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) \neq L$
2. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x) \text { DNE} \leftrightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) \text { DNE } \text{ or }\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) \text { DNE}$

I quickly ruled out 2. because by my proof above, it is clearly not the case the that the "DNE" of a limit at $a$ implies the "DNE" of the limit at $a^-$ or $a^+$.

So that means it must be 1. However, the "$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)\neq L$" portion of 1. goes against my intuition regarding what $\neg \left [\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L \right]$ equals. Is it (perhaps) valid to claim that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x) \text { DNE} \rightarrow  \displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)\neq L$?

A few months ago, I posted a question using the logic tag that asked about the difference between existence and equality in the context of limits ([Question about the difference between equality and existence in the context of limits.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110580/question-about-the-difference-between-equality-and-existence-in-the-context-of-l)). I was unable to arrive at any particular resolution regarding this distinction. If anyone could clear up my confusion, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: As to the one question you asked in the post, whether it is "valid to claim that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) \text { DNE} \rightarrow \lim_{x\to a}f(x)\neq L$": yes, that is a valid implication (though its converse is not valid). Indeed, the definition of the left-hand side is $\forall Y\in\Bbb R, \lim_{x\to a}f(x)\ne Y$, and so this implication is just applying the definition to $Y=L$.

Comment: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L $$ is an abbreviation for a slightly more complex statement. Since you tagged your question with real-analysis, it is equivalent to either
$$\forall {x_n \rightarrow a} \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = a $$
or equivalently 

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists \delta >0 \forall x: |x-a| <\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)| < \varepsilon$$

Try negating any of these statements to see what's wrong with your reasoning.

Comment: @Thomas ahhh. I see my error. I (incorrectly) assumed that $\exists L \in \mathbb R \ \forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \ \exists \delta \gt 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb R\ \left [0 \lt |x-a| \lt \delta \rightarrow |f(x)-L| \lt \varepsilon \right ]$ was logically equivalent to $\forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \ \exists \delta \gt 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb R\ \left [0 \lt |x-a| \lt \delta \rightarrow |f(x)-L| \lt \varepsilon \right ]$. I see now that while $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ implies the *existence* of some $L$, the converse is not true (be wary of the overloaded semantics behind the symbol $L$)

Answer (score 1):

The negation of
$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L$$
is
$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) \text{ DNE or } \lim_{x \to a}f(x) \neq L.$$
So the negated biconditional reads
$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) \text{ DNE or } \lim_{x \to a}f(x) \neq L \iff \lim_{x \to a^{-}}f(x) \text{ DNE or } \lim_{x \to a^{-}}f(x) \neq L \text{ or } \lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) \text{ DNE or } \lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) \neq L.$$

But to prove your statement all you need is the fact that if $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a}f(x)$.

Comment: For your final statement, you are suggesting to take the contrapositive, yes?

Comment: @S.Cramer I was thinking by contradiction. If $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ exists, it's impossible for the left and right limits to have different values.